# iframes preventing scripts from loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, visual-studio-2013

My ASP.NET MVC app involves setting up a contract for a paying customer.

It has 2 `<iframe>` elements; one containing html for a contract document, and one containing html for a receipt. This is so that they can be printed individually.

The trouble is, with the `<iframe>` elements present, my script elements are being removed.

If I remove the `<iframe>` elements, the `<script>` tags appear fine. If I put them back, they are missing.

I have tried using the `srcdoc` attribute instead of `src` but the results are the same.

The `src` URI is for the same controller as the main page, so there should not be any security issues.

Is there a way to get the scripts to load without losing the `<iframe>`s? Or do I need to just live with this and work out a better way to do it?

Someone is bound to ask, so here is the html for the `<iframe>`s:

```
<iframe id="contract" name="contract" class="print" srcdoc="@Documents.Contract(@Model.Plan.PlanId, 0)" />
<iframe id="receipt" name="receipt" class="print" srcdoc="@Documents.Receipt(@Model.Plan.PlanId)" />
```

Comment: just make iframe to call a controller, when it is called it will call the appropriate view page where you can have your scripts, css etc

Comment: That's what I did, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do it a better way.

I'll put the document HTML in separate `<div>`s and just hide the one I don't want to print.

A lot less headache!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")'></iframe>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you explain why this would work when using `SRCDOC` doesn't? Thanks

Comment: i used iframe only with src